# Get data from one table and count matching records from another

Tags: mysql, select, join, count

I'm not sure if this is possible. I have one table `members` and a second table `transactions`.

I need to get the name of the member from the `members` table, but also count the number of transactions that member has made from another table. Is this even possible in a JOIN statement, or do I need to write two statements?

```
SELECT
    m.first_name,
    m.last_name,
    COUNT(t.giver_id),
    COUNT(t.getter_id)
FROM
    members AS m
JOIN
    transactions AS t
ON
    m.id = t.giver_id
WHERE
    m.id = $i
```

I should add that it's possible a member has not made any transactions and would therefore not appear in the `transactions` table.

When I run this code, it returns all `NULL` columns. When I add the `EXPLAIN` statement, MySql says "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const table..."

Is this possible? If so, then what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Sample data structure and expected output:

```
members
id  |  first_name  |  last_name
_______________________________
1   |     Bill     |    Smith
2   |     Joe      |    Jones

transactions table
id  |  giver_id  |  getter_id  |  status
________________________________________
1   |      1     |      2      |  complete
2   |      1     |      2      |  complete
```

So running my query should return:

```
1   |   Bill   |   Smith   |   2   |   0
2   |   Joe    |   Jones   |   0   |   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple LEFT JOIN should suffice:

```
SELECT
  m.first_name,
  m.last_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.id = t.giver_id THEN 1 END) AS giver_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.id = t.getter_id THEN 1 END) AS getter_count
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN transactions AS t ON m.id = t.giver_id OR m.id = t.getter_id
GROUP BY m.first_name, m.last_name
```

Do not forget adding GROUP BY when using aggregate functions. Just because MySQL allows the query to go through without it, it doesn't mean it is advised. MySQL will pick up random row values for unaggregated columns which can be problematic. Avoid this anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried this but it incorrectly counts `t.getter_id` as the same value as `t.giver_id`. Do I need to modify the `ON` statement to allow for counting on both `t.getter_id` and `t.giver_id` columns?

Comment: Can you modify your question and provide data sample with expected output?

Comment: Sample data and expected output added.

Comment: Try the modified query.

Comment: My god it works! Thank you! It looks quite intensive though. Do you think this is an efficient solution? Also, is it possible to get the counts to return 0 instead of NULL? Thanks a million, I've spent half a day on this already!

Comment: It is efficient, don't worry about it. You can add ELSE 0 after THEN 1 or use IFNULL, COALESCE function.